Extending Euclid's Lemma on Prime Divisors to Products of $n$ Integers Using Mathematical Induction
I am working on proofing the extending Euclid' lemma about prime divisors to products of any number $n$ of integers using the principle of mathematical induction (A question coming from the book 'What is Mathematics'). Here is the lemma and the detailed exercise I am trying to solve:
Lemma: If a prime  divides a product, then p must divide a or b.
Extension to More Than Two Integers:
The extension to products of more than two integers is immediate. For example, if  divides  then by twice applying the lemma, we can show that p must divide at least one of the integers a, b, or c.  For if p divides neither a, b, nor c, then it cannot divide ab and hence can not divide (ab)c=abc.
How do we extend this argument to products of any number n?
My attempt:
Assume that the statement is true for some integer $n \geq 2$. That is, if $p$ divides the product $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$, then $p$ must divide at least one of the integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$.
We need to show that the statement is also true for $n+1$. After adding a new term $a_{n+1}$
Consider the product $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$. There are two cases to consider:

Case 1: $p$ divides $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$: By the inductive hypothesis, since $p$ divides $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$, $p$ must divide at least one of the integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. Adding another term $a_{n+1}$is the same.

Case 2: $p$ does not divide $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$: Since $p$ divides $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n a_{n+1}$ and does not divide $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$, it must be the case that $p$ divides $a_{n+1}$.


In both cases, $p$ divides at least one of the integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1}$.
By the principle of mathematical induction, the statement is true for all integers $n \geq 2$.
but I am not sure if my reasoning is correct. Could you help me verify this?

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.
